# Can I move a light switch from a 3 gang box to a second 3 gang box above it?

Tags: electrical, wiring, drill, smart-switch, diy-vs-pro

new to the forum so sorry if this is a little confusing. I just moved into a newly constructed home. At the front of the house, there are two 3-gang boxes an inch on top of one another. They are all on the same 15 amp circuit controlling entryway and outdoor lighting. The top box consists of 3 3way switches. One controls the lights on the stairs to the second floor, and the other two control outdoor lighting. The bottom box has 2 single pole switches and a 4 way switch. The first single pole controls more outside lighting. The second controls the entryway chandelier. The 4 way controls recessed lights in the entryway. It makes no sense to me why this wasn't wired with the 3 inside lights in one box and the 3 outside lights in the other. To change the order without completely rewiring, I am adding Lutron Caseta smart switches to the respective 3way/4way switches and placing a wall mounted pico remote in the switch locations in the front of the house. I can program these to wirelessly control any lutron switch, allowing me to change the order of 4 of the 6 switches. However, that leaves me with 2 single pole switches in the same box, one controlling outside lights and the other controlling the chandelier inside. I included a picture of my halfway point of changing the switches. The single pole switches are red and multiway are black.

Is there an easy way for me to move the chandelier from the bottom to the top box without removing all the wiring and box? I thought about somehow drilling a hole and pigtailing between boxes, but I'm assuming this is against code. I know this sounds like a lot of work for little gain, but I've been in the house for 3 months and my wife and I can never remember which is which. [image][image]

Comment: If your top box has an always hot, I'd just remove enough drywall to run a 14-2 from the top box to the bottom, with one end tied in as a switched hot on the switch and the other end pigtailed to the existing switched hot in the bottom box. If your top box only has travelers coming in, I can't think of an easy solution except the obvious to run an additional cable to carry an always hot from the bottom box.

Comment: What a nightmare I don’t think I have seen such a mess in 45 years of doing this work. They probably had to add the second box for wire fill reasons. It may be possible to move things but to tell the truth I would not try without taking the sheetrock off. I think I counted 15 white wires between the 2 boxes was every light in the system brought back to this location. Take lots of photos before trying to move anything I would get wire markers and mark them because that mess could confuse a pro.

Comment: "that mess could confuse a pro" - no kidding, holy smoke!  And that's why I own 11 colors of THHN wire and 10 colors of electrical tape.  It's a shame the installer used plastic boxes, I'd have used metal boxes and run three 1/2" conduit nipples between them, to make reconfig easy...

Comment: Can you post close-ups of the insides of both boxes please?